# ¿Un concejo de buenas prácticas para guardar 50 registros o más en una base de datos Mysql Con Django?

Tags: django, python-3.7

Tengo una tabla de 10 columnas x 50 filas , y los datos están en inputs html , de momento lo hago con un **for** y lo guardo en la base de datos, pero que tan factible es hacerlo así. ?

ejemplo:

```
for a,b,c,d... in zip(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4 ...):
   datos = Modelo(campo1=a , campo2 = b, campo3 = c, campo4=d ...)
   datos.save()
   #este bucle se repetirá 50 veces o mas
```

**Como podría realizar esta práctica de una mejor manera y que todos los registros se guarden correctamente.**

Comment: ¿Has leido sobre [*bulk insert*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_insert)? Busca cómo hacerlo para tu motor de base de datos. Además, seguramente necesitarás aplicar *transacciones*. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacerlo seria utilizando el método [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> ```
> instances = []
>
> for a,b,c,d... in zip(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4 ...):
>    instances.append(Modelo(campo1=a , campo2 = b, campo3 = c, campo4=d ...))
>
> Modelo.objects.bulk_create(instances)
> ```
>
> Este método inserta la lista de objetos proporcionada en la base de
> datos de manera eficiente (generalmente solo 1 consulta, sin importar
> cuántos objetos haya)

Mas que una buena practica, se trata de optimizacion, y evidentemente es una buena practica.

Por otra parte me parece que te complicas por las santas respecto a los campos (`zip(...)`), estoy seguro que habría una mejor forma de gestionarlo, pero no se el contexto del código. Observa la situación y encuentra una mejor manera.

Espero haberte ayudado.